# How to deserialize deeply nested JSON without separate classes for each level

Tags: java, json, jackson, tree-traversal

Say in Java I want to deserialize a JSON string such as:

```
{ 
  "classb": {
    "c": "myc"
   }
}
```

So I can create model classes like so:

```
@Data
class Classa {
     Classb classb;
}

@Data
class Classb {
    String c;
}
```

And print the deserialized value like so:

```
System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Classa.class).getClassb().getC()  );
```

So my question is, when we are only interested in a value that is deeply nested in class objects and we need a getter for that value, do we have to create a separate model class for each object, or is there a way to create a single model class which contains the nested classes like this, and be able to access the inner objects with a getter, like  `getC()`

```
@Data
class Classa {
    class Classb {
        String c;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using?  GSON?  Jackson?

Comment: Using Jackson ObjectMapper here

Answer (score 0):

You can implement one of the tree-traversal algorithms, for instance [*Depth first search algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), and iterate over the tree of Nodes until the target property wasn't found (or until the tree is fully explored).

That how iterative implementation of the Depth first search based on functionality of the Jackson's `JsonNode` might look like:

```
public static <T> T search(String json, String target, Class<T> tClass) throws JsonProcessingException {
    
    JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);

    T result = null;
    
    Deque<JsonNode> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    stack.push(node);

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        JsonNode current = stack.pop();
    
        if (current.isContainerNode()) {
        
            for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = current.fields(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            
                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> next = it.next();

                if (next.getKey().equals(target)) {
                    result = tClass.cast(next.getValue());
                }
                
                stack.push(next.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And that's how Depth first search can implemented recursively. Instead of returning `null` as a default value we can change the return type to `Optional` (it can be done in the previous version as well).

```
public static <T> Optional<T> search(String json, String target, Class<T> tClass) throws JsonProcessingException {
    
    JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json);
    Object result = search(node, target);
    
    return result != null ? Optional.of(tClass.cast(result)) : Optional.empty();
}

public static Object search(JsonNode node, String target) {
    if (!node.isContainerNode()) return null;
    
    Object result = null;

    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = node.fields(); it.hasNext() && result == null; ) {
        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> next = it.next();
    
        if (next.getKey().equals(target)) {
            return next.getValue();
        }
        result = search(next.getValue(),target);
    }
    return result;
}
```